# Create an object from an array of objects using the value from one object as the key for the new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, async-await, supabase

Newbie here trying trying to create an object from an array I am getting from Supabase when I filter on certain cities.

Here is what the data looks like coming in:

```
[
    {
        "weather": "sunny",
        "percentage": "31"
    },
    {
        "weather": "rain",
        "percentage": "19"
    },
    {
        "weather": "cloudy",
        "percentage": "35"
    },
    {
        "weather": "snow",
        "percentage": "15"
    }
]
```

How can I take that and create this?

```
{
    sunny: 31,
    rain: 19,
    cloudy: 35,
    snow: 15,
}
```

I've tried searching through multiple questions here without much luck but if this is answered elsewhere please point me to it.  I am new to JS and been through tutorial hell but can't seem to get this to output what I need.

Here is the async function to get the data from Supabase:

```
    async function getData() {
        const { data, error } = await supabase
            .from('cities')
            .select('weather, percentage')
            .match({ city: targetCity });
        if (error) throw new Error(error.message);
```

The closest I have gotten is to use this:

```
const result = data.map(Object.values);
console.log(result);
```

Which gives this output but it is still arrays:

```
(4) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
0: (2) ['sunny', '31']
1: (2) ['rain', '19']
2: (2) ['cloudy', '35']
3: (2) ['snow', '15']
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let input = [
    {
        "weather": "sunny",
        "percentage": "31"
    },
    {
        "weather": "rain",
        "percentage": "19"
    },
    {
        "weather": "cloudy",
        "percentage": "35"
    },
    {
        "weather": "snow",
        "percentage": "15"
    }
]

let output = {}

for (let elem of input ) {
    output[elem.weather] = elem.percentage 
}

console.log(output)
```

There are other ways to do it. But I am going with a simple loop as it is easier to understand. Let me know if this doesn't make sense.